# visualforcePage.getContent() : Maximum redirects (100) exceeded

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, session-id

We are having utility class where we are fetching session Id using `visualforcePage.getContent()` which we are further using in updating custom metadata records.

we released our last version around  `Nov - 2018`
till now same code was working fine but now when we released our new beta version we started getting this issue where it says

> Maximum redirects (100) exceeded.

we checked couple of solutions online and we did update our code based on solution suggested here 
[Asynchronous getContent hit org.apache.commons.httpclient.RedirectException: Maximum redirects (100) exceeded](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175386/asynchronous-getcontent-hit-org-apache-commons-httpclient-redirectexception-max)

but still the same case.

We found out known issue around it and it says its resolved but its not working for us. any help will be greatly appriciated
[Summer 14 Regression- Under some circumstances PageReference.getContent() or getContentAsPDF()fails the error- System.VisualforceException: org.apac](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4nnAAC&title=summer-14-regression-under-some-circumstances-pagereference-getcontent-or-getcontentaspdf-fails-the-error-system-visualforceexception-org-apac)

Here is the code we are using

```
/**
 * @description Method to fetch session id from GetSessionIdVF visualforce page
 * @param NA
 * @return  string  returns valid session id
 *
*/
public static String fetchUserSessionId(){
     String sessionId = '';
     // Get the content of the VF page
     String vfContent;
     String ns = MyApexClass.getNamespacePrefix();

    /* Old code we were using
    // Refer to the Page
    PageReference reportPage = Page.GetSessionIdVF;
    try{
        if(!test.isRunningTest()){
            vfContent = reportPage.getContent().toString();
        }
        else {
            vfContent = String.valueOf('Start_Of_Session_Id Test End_Of_Session_Id');
        }
        // Find the position of Start_Of_Session_Id and End_Of_Session_Id
        Integer startP = vfContent.indexOf('Start_Of_Session_Id') + 'Start_Of_Session_Id'.length(),
        endP = vfContent.indexOf('End_Of_Session_Id');
        // Get the Session Id
        sessionId = vfContent.substring(startP, endP);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.debug('***** ex: ' + ex);            
    }
    */
    //End of Old code , we commented out for now

    // After updating logic as per online solution new code
    try{
        String vf_url = '/apex/';
        if(String.isNotBlank(ns)) {
            vf_url += ns + '__' + 'getsessionidvf';    
        }
        else {
            vf_url += 'getsessionidvf';       
        }


        PageReference pg = new PageReference(vf_url);

        if(!test.isRunningTest()){
            vfContent = pg.getContent().toString();
        }
        else {
            vfContent = String.valueOf('Start_Of_Session_Id Test End_Of_Session_Id');
        }

        Integer startP = vfContent.indexOf('Start_Of_Session_Id') + 'Start_Of_Session_Id'.length(),
        endP = vfContent.indexOf('End_Of_Session_Id');
        // Get the Session Id
        sessionId = vfContent.substring(startP, endP);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.debug('***** ex: ' + ex);
    }

    // Return Session Id
    return sessionId;
 }
```

Comment: We'll probably need to see your code.

Comment: @gNerb added code snippet

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande have u had any success and able to get past this error?

Comment: @VarunC nope not yet

Comment: Running into the same issue. Seems to have started recently for us.

Comment: @Eric let me know if you find any solution

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande Did you find the solution? Can you share it.

Comment: @lambad nope not yet !

Comment: i have the exact issue right now! Anyone has been able to fix it?